# Block row and column CollectionView scroll

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

And this is my code :

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView?
var collectionViewSeries: UICollectionView?
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Year
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView?.scrollEnabled = false

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

    // Series
    let layoutSeries: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layoutSeries.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layoutSeries.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
    layoutSeries.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    collectionViewSeries = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layoutSeries)
    collectionViewSeries!.dataSource = self
    collectionViewSeries!.delegate = self
    collectionViewSeries!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellSeries")
    collectionViewSeries!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionViewSeries?.scrollEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(collectionViewSeries!)
}
```

**My question:**

I'm trying to block the first column and the first row by scrolling.
   So that only the central cells can flow.

This is an example of what I want to do:

[link](http://code4app.net/ios/Static-column-table/50fe649d6803fa7b65000001)

Thanks

Comment: should the data cells be scrollable in both ways ??

Comment: Yes... As you can see in the video link

Comment: http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns ... does this one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrolling cannot be disabled for a particular cell. You create a UIView in Section Header similar to Cell 1. This will work as you like.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init]; //your view 
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you get me a simple example please ?

Comment: Thanks.
I edited the new code. But when he created the second CollectionView goes wrong. Can you understand why?

Comment: second collection view? can you explain me more

Comment: when I create collectionViewSeries and do:  self.view.addSubview(collectionViewSeries!) it faults

Comment: but if I create only "CollectionView" working properly

Comment: In other words, I can not create more CollectionView

Comment: have a section header for all your collection views

Comment: Please can get me an example ?